# for how long can a background service run on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, background-service

Is the background service limited to 10 minutes, or could it run for hours? And is there any way the user can shut down the background service while it is running?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the code, you can run the background service forever or close it as soon as the app has been exited. Apart from that, OS itself can close the background service if no action is performed by it for several minutes.

Comment: And how can one run the background service forever? Any information about forever running background service is appreciated.